# Convert JSON string to C# dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON string

```
{
  "Date":"21/11/2010"
  "name": "TEST"
  "place":"xyz"
}
```

I want to convert it into a C# dictionary without using a third party library

Comment: maybe you can use a second-party

Comment: Do not downvote because you dislike the choice to use no 3rd Party libs. Maybe there is a good reason for. So clarify before judging

Comment: No there's not. You do not have to reinvent the wheel everytime.
But if he wants to, then he should show us his effort and the exact problem.

Comment: Shouldn't those prop-value pairs be comma-separated?

Comment: Sometimes understanding what a framework does is quite helpful instead blindly using it. So learning would be a reason not to choose a whole API for just one small feature.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih What about frameworks that do not allow the use of external libraries... yes they do exist.

Comment: @Arsenal An example? How can another library limit your use of external libraries?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Not another library, but rather another framework. Take Microsoft Dynamics CRM for example, where you upload your custom dll's and they get executed through reflection. The only way to include another library is to use IL Merge to merge the (strongly-signed- assembly with your dll. This raises a lot of other complications within the framework (max. dll size and so on). I can image a developer rather having a native solution that does not require merging assemblies (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2010/11/09/how-to-reference-assemblies-from-plug-ins/).

Comment: Often times, 3rd-party libs are hard-to-find (broken links, wandering through someone's GitHub source, assuming it's built on today's runtime environment: compatible with the latest .NET Framework, 64-bit, etc.), have a cost associated with them (either in money or ramp-up time scouring endless mountains of implementation methods), and often downloads are prohibited on corporate networks where we are trying to build these solutions.  So those that prefer 3rd-party libs as solutions, it's often hurting, not helping the community-at-large.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do it natively since net 3.5 with jsonserializer.

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(jsonText);
var place = dict["place"]; // "xyz"
```

Here is a simple tutorial for your case: [Quick JSON Serialization/Deserialization in C#](http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c)

Requires the `System.Web.Extensions` reference. If you can't find it, your program is probably using a Client target framework. Use a "Full" target framework.

Comment: THX xanatos am on my Smartphone so editing is quite unconvenient. Nice work

Comment: that doesn't work for me (VS2010).  it breaks with the error "No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String'"

Comment: @zewa666 Thanks man!! I spent 4 hours behind this and found extremely good solution. This solution follows KISS principal.

Comment: Same problem as @ekkis, doesn't work for me as shown, however, using `<string, dynamic>` or just `dynamic` as show when you follow the tutorial link does.

Answer (score 1):

You can now (for a while) use the inbuilt `System.Text.Json` for this as follows:

```
var dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
```